# Form value not updating

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I'm new in testing and till now have succedded in setting up Testing using the ng-cli. I am currently testing a simple login form. This is how far I've come up with

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  showError: boolean = false;
  verfiedUser: boolean = true;

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, private _router: Router, private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => this.verfiedUser = (params['verified'] === 'true'));
  }

  loginPassword (value): void {
    // this.auth.login(value.username, value.password).subscribe(response => console.log(response), err => console.log(err));
  }
}
```

login.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement }    from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import {
  ActivatedRoute, ActivatedRouteStub, click, newEvent, Router, RouterStub
} from '../testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

import {
  HttpModule, Http, XHRBackend, Response, ResponseOptions
} from '@angular/http';

import { AppModule } from '../app.module';

function createEvent(eventType: any): Event {
  const evt: Event = document.createEvent('Event');
  evt.initEvent(eventType, true, true);
  return evt;
}

describe('LoginComponent (templateUrl)', () => {

  let comp:    LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
  let de:      DebugElement;
  let el:      HTMLElement;
  let loginForm: FormGroup;

  // async beforeEach
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    let activatedRoute = new ActivatedRouteStub();

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();  // compile template and css
  }));

  // synchronous beforeEach
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);

    comp = fixture.componentInstance; // BannerComponent test instance
    loginForm = comp.loginForm;
  });

  it('should have a login form which is clean and disabled', () => {
    const loginBtn: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.login-form button[type="submit"]'));

    console.log(comp, comp.loginForm, loginForm);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    console.log(comp, comp.loginForm, loginForm);

    expect(comp.loginForm.value).toEqual({
      username: '',
      password: ''
    }, 'does not match');

    expect(loginBtn.nativeElement.disabled).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

I'm currently stuck with these errors.
1. `loginForm` is undefined, though `comp` and `comp.loginForm` is defined.
2. Even after `fixture.detectChanges()` the form is not updating.

Any help, in the right direction will help.

UPDATE
updated `beforeEach` method

```
beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();  // compile template and css
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);

    comp = fixture.componentInstance; // BannerComponent test instance
  });
```

Thanks,

Comment: Is there any reason why you have put 2 beforeEach methods in here? My best guess is that the async beforeEach is not compiling the components fast enough for your other beforeEach to be able to grab the component instance from the TestBed. Try putting all the setup code into the first beforeEach to see if that solves our problem to start with

Comment: I did as you said, @peppermcknight. I've updated the answer. The problem still remains.

Comment: In example [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1qzSB8u0z3bnlV1ZrrRh?p=preview) test was passed